# Splashscreen Not working in cordova phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I have gone through all the cordova docs about splashscreen and answers about splashscreen issues but none of them is working please, How can I make my splashscreen to be visible in my phonegap app?

this is my config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-7.0.1' />
<preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='1' />   
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="120000" />        
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="~1.2.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.7" />  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="~2.3.1" />     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.6" />   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" spec="~1.2.5" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="~1.0.7" />   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.3" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.3" />  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="~1.0.7" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~3.0.1" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.4.3" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.3" />  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.3" />     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="~2.1.5" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.3" />    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.2" />        <allow-navigation href="https://www.medicaladvicehub.com/mob/*" />

<icon src="icon.png" />

<splash src="splash.png" /> <platform name="android">   <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />  <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />  <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />  <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />  <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />  <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" /> </platform> <platform name="ios">  <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />     <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />  <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />   <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />  <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />     <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />  <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />     <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />     <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />  <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />     <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />  <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />     <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />   <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />    <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />    <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />  <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />     <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />   <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />    <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />    <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />     <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />     <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />  <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" /> </platform> <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/storelogo.png" target="StoreLogo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/smalllogo.png" target="Square30x30Logo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.png" target="Square70x70Logo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.png" target="Square71x71Logo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.png" target="Square310x310Logo" />

    <splash src="res/screens/windows/splashscreen.png" target="SplashScreen"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/splashscreenphone.png" target="SplashScreenPhone"/> </platform>
<access origin="*" /> </widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Cheers.

Comment: It is installed from npm during build with phonegap the config.xml didnt paste well but if you look closely cordover splashscreen plugin is there and i ve changed it to 5.0.2 but still no splashscreen ..

Comment: sorry for my late response i think it might be compatibility issues, i have the cordova-plugin-splashscreen included and have tried two different versions, it used to show when I used the CLI 6.xxx I used the the new CLI 7.... thats when the issue atarted I have reverted back but still no difference I actually just inserted a HTML file with a gif loading for now ... Thanks anyway